# Open/Close/Manage Windows 8 apps via WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-8

Is it possible to open or to **manage at all Windows 8 apps** (e.g. the built-in Mail or News app) via **WinAPI functions from a desktop program**?

With '*manage*', I mean to open, close, snap (to left and right) or to enumerate Windows 8 apps.

I know that apps can register for special URI schemes so they can be opened by a link (and probably via `ShellExecute()` and related functions), but what if they don't?

---

I've just found a blog post of *Ashwin Needamangala* in a Win8 App Dev blog which covers app activation and automating lifecycle states with C++, WinAPI and COM: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx

Comment: No, desktop apps have no knowledge of or access to the Metro side of things (and vice versa). Never the twain shall meet :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter It's a shame. I always thought that one has the biggest control over Windows using C/WinAPI, but now there is a major part of Windows which can't be 'really' controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumeration works via the [PackageManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx) class.
Opening an app is possible using the [IApplicationActivationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/hh706902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. 
And if you're the one who opened it and you have a handle, you can probably call [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it, too, but I haven't tried that one.

Edit: we open-sourced our [apprunner utility](https://github.com/doo/metro-driver), it can install, run and uninstall packages and shows the use of PackageManager and IApplicationActivationManager.

Apart from that, other interaction (i.e. snapping/unsnapping) doesn't seem to be possible from the outside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how could I use the *PackageManager* in raw C/C++ using WinAPI **without .NET**? BTW I would be really interested in your utility.

Comment: Our utility is now open-sourced: https://github.com/doo/metro-driver The PackageManager class is a class from WinRT, which makes setting up the project a bit awkward, see our repo for a sample.